# Jar file not working correctly

Tags: java, jar

I create .jar file in eclipse. I use .jar file to print text on pos printer. My program is printing correctly, but when I start .jar file is not connecting with the printer. For connecting with the printer I use javax.comm library.

Comment: There must be some exception raised. can you post the log overhere

Comment: goto command prompt , fire the following command `java -jar yourjar.jar`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/comm/... Thanks

Comment: How can add the comm.jar file into my jar file ?

Comment: So the issue is clear that runtime there is no required dependent library available

Comment: @JigarJoshi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2533/discussion-between-gogoo-and-jigar-joshi)

Answer (score 1):

Open up the jar in achiever tool edit Menifest.txt add the following

```
Class-Path: /path/to/requiredLibary.jar
```

**Also See**

- [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is the javax.comm jar in the classpath when you start the jar from the command line?
Something like:

```
java -cp myproject.jar;javax-comm-3.0.jar com.mycompany.MyMainClass
```

Note that the `java -jar myproject.jar` is incompatible with `-cp`, ie this **doesn't** work: `java -cp javax-comm-3.0.jar -jar myproject.jar`

Comment: same is true for the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, it is **not** used when running a JAR (`java -jar ...` or double-clicking it)